# navigation.push('SearchPage', {search_params: item.school_type}); naviagtion.push does not changing screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I use `navigation.navigate('SearchPage', {search_params: item.school_type});` then when i click to the card search_params passed only once , second time search params not passed . When i use `navigation.push('SearchPage', {search_params: item.school_type});` then params passed but screen is not changing

here is component code

```
import React from 'react';
import {withNavigation} from '@react-navigation/compat';
import {Image, StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback,Alert} from 'react-native';
import {Block, Text, theme} from 'galio-framework';

class SchoolCategoryCards extends React.Component {



render() {
    const {navigation, item, horizontal, full, style, ctaColor, imageStyle} = this.props;

    const imageStyles = [
      full ? styles.fullImage : styles.horizontalImage,
      imageStyle
    ];
const cardContainer = [styles.card, styles.shadow, style];
const imgContainer = [styles.imageContainer,
  horizontal ? styles.horizontalStyles : styles.verticalStyles,
  styles.shadow
];

return (
  <Block row={horizontal} card flex style={cardContainer}>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback  onPress={() => {
      navigation.push('SearchPage', {search_params: item.school_type});
    }}>
      <Block flex style={imgContainer}>
        <Image source={{uri: item.image}} style={imageStyles}/>
      </Block>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
      Alert.alert("Clicked");
      /*this.props.navigation.navigate('SearchPage', {search_params: item.school_type});*/
    }}>
      <Block flex space="between" style={styles.cardDescription}>
        <Text size={14} style={styles.cardTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
      </Block>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  </Block>
);
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  card: {
    backgroundColor: theme.COLORS.WHITE,
    marginVertical: theme.SIZES.BASE,
    borderWidth: 0,
    minHeight: 114,
    marginBottom: 16
  },
  cardHeading: {
    flex: 1,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    fontWeight: "700",
  },
  cardTitle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    paddingBottom: 6,
    fontWeight: "700",
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 15
  },
  cardDescription: {
    padding: theme.SIZES.BASE / 2
  },
  imageContainer: {
    borderRadius: 3,
    elevation: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  image: {
    // borderRadius: 3,
  },
  horizontalImage: {
    height: 100,
    width: 'auto',
  },
  horizontalStyles: {
    borderTopRightRadius: 0,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
  },
  verticalStyles: {
    borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 0
  },
  fullImage: {
    height: 150
  },
  shadow: {
    shadowColor: theme.COLORS.BLACK,
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 2},
    shadowRadius: 4,
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    elevation: 2,
  },
});

export default withNavigation(SchoolCategoryCards);
```

Comment: how can you see the params is passed if screen is not changing in navigation.push?

Comment: In search page i used console.log to print params @GauravRoy

Comment: so its navigating there but the page is not showing?

Comment: When i used naviagtion.push then params is going and its printed in console but screen is not changed but when i use navigation.navigate then only first time params passed not in second time

Answer (score 0):

When you use drawerNaviagtion then page stored in cache 
To remove cache use this

```
 unmountOnBlur={true}
                 options={{unmountOnBlur: true}}
```

Example :

```
<Drawer.Screen name="SchoolDetails" component={DetailPageStack} unmountOnBlur={true}
                     options={{unmountOnBlur: true}}/>
```

This solves my params cache issue .

Answer (score -1):

Try this option

```
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';


const pushAction = StackActions.push('SearchPage', { search_params: item.school_type});


navigation.dispatch(pushAction);
```

Comment: Not working getting error 

The action 'PUSH' with payload {"name":"SearchPage","params":{"search_params":2}} was not handled by any navigator.

Comment: function SearchStack(props) {
  return (<Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="screen">
      <Stack.Screen name="SearchPage" component={SearchPage}
                    options={{
                      header: ({navigation, scene}) => (
                        <Header back title="Search Page" navigation={navigation}/>
                      )
                    }}
                    initialParams={{search_params: props.route.params.search_params}}/>
    
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

this is my searchstack function